# Why is pg_restore unable to create database with --create option before restoring from dump?

Tags: postgresql, restore, linux, pg-restore

Why pg_restore is unable to create database with --create option before restoring from dump?

```
pg_restore --username=myuser --create --dbname=mydb --verbose  mybackup
```

Error,

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: FATAL:  database "mydb" does not exist
```

Comment: ,As per your error log it's clearly say that your 'mydb' does not exist.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a database, it needs to be able to connect to your database server in order to issue the "CREATE DATABASE" command.  Connecting to the server requires you to specify an existing database to connect under, and obviously that cannot be the database which fails to exist and which is to be created.  There are special databases usually reserved for maintenance operations, usually `postgres`, which you can connect to for this purpose.

When using `--create` mode, `--dbname` specifies not the name of the database to be restored into, but rather the name of the database to be used to create the other database.

Comment: then how do you specify the name of the database to be created?

Comment: With the --create option, the name of the database to be created comes from the dump file itself.  It is the same as the name of the database that was dumped.

Comment: Ahh I see. Is there a way to make the newly created database have another name with using --create?

Answer (score 0):

Without `-C` it works as expected.  For example, if I wanted to make a exampleDB_dev based on exampleDB, I would do the following:

```
pg_dump -Fc exampleDB > exampleDB_temp.dump
dropdb exampleDB_dev
<created empty exampleDB_dev database>
pg_restore -d exampleDB_dev exampleDB_temp.dump
```